# Hahn Banachs's first geometric form

Tags: functional-analysis

In Brezis' Functional Analysis... on the demonstration of the first geometric form.

A and B are disjoint. Why does he asks to check that C=A-B is convex? $A\cap B=\emptyset$. C should be just A, that is convex, isn´t it?

And again  he takes $C=\bigcup_{y\in B}(A-y)$ to say that C is open. but $A-y=A$.

Whats the point?

Comment: $A - B$ doesn't mean the set difference $A\setminus B$, it means $\{ a - b : a \in A, b \in B\}$.

Comment: it´s true. Thank you very much!